What size adapter do I need for an internally threaded aerator that measures 20.9 mm across to fit a Pur faucet filter?
None of the adapters that were provided by Pur for their faucet filter fits my Kohler Parq internally threaded aerator faucet.  The existing aerator measures 21 mm diameter from outside edge of thread to outside edge of thread, the Pur Faucet connection measures 21.4mm from edge to edge.
https://www.kohler.com/en/products/kitchen-faucets/shop-kitchen-faucets/parq-three-hole-deck-mount-bridge-kitchen-sink-faucet-w-9-gooseneck-matching-finish-sidespray-and-lever-handles-6131-4
https://www.pur.com/shop/faucet-systems/pur-plus-faucet-filtration-system-horizontal-chrome/
Is that a standard size - if so what size is it?
